# Win10 only boots in safe mode after CPU and RAM upgrade

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, amd-ryzen

**Setting**

I bought a new CPU and new RAM for my PC.

> old CPU(Amd Ryzen 5 1500X) -> new CPU(Amd Ryzen 7 3700X)
>
> old RAM(8GB DDR4 2400) -> new RAM(2x16GB DDR4 3200)

I didn't change my mainboard:

> ASRock AB350 Pro4

Other hardware that is still the same

> GeForce GTX 1050Ti
>
> Some hard drives

I upgraded my BIOS as described in the [support](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/#BIOS) to version 5.8 which is required for Ryzen 3000 CPUs as described [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/index.asp#CPU).

I have two separated SSD hard drives, one running Ubuntu 18.04 and the other one Windows10.

**Problem**

If I boot Ubuntu everything works just fine. However when I want to boot my windows partition I'm getting stuck in the loading screen of the Windows symbol.

I created a bootable USB device following [this post](https://techbit.ca/2019/02/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-uefi-usb-drive-using-linux/) and set with `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot network` and `bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy` my default boot to safe boot and also allowed further booting options pressing `F8` during booting.

Now when I boot into the Windows partion with safe boot everything works fine. CPU and RAM are detected by BIOS and also by Windows in safe mode.

I thought, I could now try to clean boot out of save mode following [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) and the try to update all drivers. However if I try to clean boot, I end up in the same problem like before, being stuck at the forever spinning wheel.

<s>I can't upgrade Windows in safe mode and I also can't upgrade Windows from the USB Stick, because it is telling me that I should do this when Windows booted normally... I don't really know what to do now.</s>

*Edit*:
The repair tool doesn't work. So I don't really see any options, what to do.

**Question**

Do I have to reinstall Windows again or is there another option to make it work again without it?

Comment: Why are you trying to upgrade Windows?  If you install the old processor (in order to verify the Windows installation can boot), does it work?

Comment: Good question actually. I thought that this might install missing or broken drivers, since there is no other option rather than re installing or upgrading. I could boot before I installed the new processor, but I can check again.

Comment: Other question: If windows boots in safe mode, isn't this enough to verify that the Windows installation can boot in general? If not, why?

Comment: Performing an upgrade won’t install missing drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found someone having a [similar issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/eenwsq/windows_wont_boot_after_installing_new_cpu_ryzen/). The problem was caused by the `amd_sata.inf` driver. Removing the driver from offline Windows OS following [this post](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/617868/uninstall-offline-windows-os-drivers-with-dism-command/) solved the issue.

**If the Link is broken at some point:**

From now on we assume that Windows is installed on `D:`.

- run `dism /image:D:\ /Get-Drivers` in cmd from bootable USB
- search for the `amd_sata.inf` driver and look for the published name which should be something like `oem5.inf`
- remove the driver via `dism /Image:D:\ /Remove-Driver /Driver:oem5.inf`
- disable safe boot if enabled via `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot`
- reboot and everything should be fine again